# Grafana dashboard not displaying pod name instead pod_name

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-pod

I have deployed application on kubernetes cluster and for monitoring using prometheus and grafana. For kubernetes pods monitoring using Grafana dashboard: *Kubernetes cluster monitoring (via Prometheus) https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/315*

I had imported the dashboard using id 315 and its reflecting without pod name and containers name instead getting pod_name . Can anyone pls help how can i get pod name and container name in dashboard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide: 1. Screen of Settings > Variables 2.What version of Kubernetes are you using? I see that article was updated 2 yaers ago. 3. Your env is On-Perm or local? 4. Could you add your metrics query?

Comment: @PjoterS: Added screen setting of variable and kubernetes version is v1.17.0. This is my local environment project. This is not metrics query i have imported dashboard using *https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/315*

Comment: thanks it works for me in Kubernetes 1.16 metrics labels like pod_name and container_name was removed. Instead of that you need to use pod and container. You can verify it here.

Answer (score 9):

Provided tutorial was updated **2 years ago**.

Current version of Kubernetes is [1.17](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/#v1-17-0). As per tags, tutorial was tested on `Prometheus v. 1.3.0`, `Kubernetes v.1.4.0` and `Grafana v.3.1.1` which are quite old at the moment.

In requirements you have statement:

> Prometheus will use metrics provided by **cAdvisor via kubelet** service (runs on each node of Kubernetes cluster by default) and via kube-apiserver service only.

In `Kubernetes 1.16` metrics labels like `pod_name` and `container_name` was removed. Instead of that you need to use `pod` and `container`. You can verify it [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.16.md#removed-metrics).

> Any Prometheus queries that match `pod_name` and `container_name` labels (e.g. cadvisor or kubelet probe metrics) must be updated to use pod and container instead.

Please check [this Github Thread](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/18827) about dashboard bug for more information.

**Solution**

Please change `pod_name` to `pod` in your query.

Comment: No where i have manually mentioned the pod_name or container_name. I have imported the dashboard using https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/315. Can you pls help what need to be done. thanks

Comment: You are using K8s 1.17 which removed `pod_name`. In your variables you have `$pod_name` with labal_values(..... ,`pod_name`). You need change `pod_name` to `pod` in `JSON Model`. If you are using somewhere in this dashboard `container_name` you also need to change it to `container`.

Comment: I have downloaded the json file of https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1621 and replaced the pod_name to pod and container_name to container in "expr" and "legendFormat"  but still not working.

Comment: "expr": "sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=\"\",name=~\"^k8s_.*\",kubernetes_io_hostname=~\"^$Node$\"}[1m])) by (pod)",
              "interval": "10s",
              "intervalFactor": 1,
              "legendFormat": "{{ pod }}",
              "metric": "container_cpu",
              "refId": "A",
              "step": 10

Comment: As I mentioned before, you used old version of Grafana, old Json file (last update 3 years ago.)  and Kubernetes 1.17 which I dont think they are compatible. Please download latest version of Grafana 6.5.3

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes version v1.16.0 has Removed cadvisor metric labels `pod_name` and `container_name` to match instrumentation guidelines. Any Prometheus queries that match `pod_name` and `container_name` labels (e.g. cadvisor or kubelet probe metrics) must be updated to use `pod` and `container` instead.

You can check:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.16.md#metrics-changes