# GKE 1.16.9 Prometheus, grafana per pod details not working?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I have a GKE cluster running kubernetes 1.16.9. I'm trying to get a monitoring system working using Prometheus, and Grafana.

The dashboard I'm using is the standard "Kubernetes Cluster Monitoring"
https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/315

When I import it though, I can't see the pod-by-pod CPU/Memory usage, I just see "value":
[image: grafana dashboard not working image]

I have another cluster with an almost identical setup using kubernetes 1.15  and the dashboard works perfectly showing each pod and the usage of each pod.

Why is this the case? I'm fairly new to understanding prometheus/grafana and how all this works together.

[image: working image]

What could be causing this issue? The metrics are showing, and kubectl top pod shows up... so I think metrics-server is working well...

Any tips on trying to debug this?

Comment: In my case, when I install Prometheus & Grafana from the GKE marketplace and see pod metrics, the CPU and memory usage are all "No data points", although ahere are pods running. It resembles this issue: https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/19597

Answer (score 2):

You are not alone with this problem. The things are like that: `pod_name` and `container_name` [labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) coming from the [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) were deprecated in 1.14 in favor of pod and container, then removed in [1.16](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.16/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.16.md#metrics-changes)

> Removed metrics
>
> Removed cadvisor metric labels pod_name and
> container_name to match instrumentation guidelines. Any Prometheus
> queries that match pod_name and container_name labels (e.g. cadvisor
> or kubelet probe metrics) must be updated to use pod and container
> instead. (#80376, @ehashman)

so as per above -
Any Prometheus queries that match `pod_name` and `container_name` labels (e.g. cadvisor or kubelet probe metrics) must be updated to use `pod` and `container` instead

Very similar question for your reference - [Grafana dashboard not displaying pod name instead pod_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625516/grafana-dashboard-not-displaying-pod-name-instead-pod-name)

btw, have you tries this one? https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/11143

Comment: Thank you very much.
Fixed the issue by simply changing the query from using pod_name to just pod. Worked right away. Easy fix. Thanks a lot.